# Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\book]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to seed database 
when I use this

```
 public function run()
{
   factory(\App\User::class,10)->create()->each(function ($user){
        $user->books()->save(factory(\App\book::class)->make());
    });
}
```

i can add 10 user in database but i cant add 10 book in database

```
 $factory->define(App\Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'name' =>$faker->name(),
    'pages' =>$faker->randomNumber(4),
    'ISBN' =>$faker->randomNumber(10),
    'price' =>$faker->randomNumber(4),
    'published_at'=>$faker->date()
];});
```

Show me error

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\book].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is case sensitive, so try using:

```
factory(\App\User::class,10)->create()->each(function ($user){
    $user->books()->save(factory(\App\Book::class)->make());
});
```

Notice the capitalized `Book` instead of `book`.